# Phusion Passenger doesn't write log files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have installed phussion passenger on osx following [this guide from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/PhusionRails/_index.html). I also used the PassengerPane to configure it.

It works, but it doesn't write anything to development.log. It's not a permissions problem.

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it.

Logging wasn't working because of these lines in application.rb:

```
config.logger    = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.log_level = :info
```

These were required for using Heroku's logging, but not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Passenger runs on production by default. Check production.log, you should see content there.

Comment: I doesn't write to production.log either. But it shouldn't because "development" is checked in PassengerPane.

Comment: It's not Passenger's fault, logging is handled by Rails. But try checking the Apache global error log, see if there's anything in there that tells you more about the problem.